# How to access google groups api using RESTful client?

Tags: google-api, restful-authentication, google-groups-api

I need to add member to my existing group from a web app using HTTP request, i am not able to understand how to get auth token so that i can access the endpoint. Below is the endpoint which i want to access.

[Google group member insert](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/insert)

Comment: um Google groups is a forum. you linked Google Apps Admin SDK
which is for google apps domain.   Which are you using?

Comment: Am not using any sdk client, i want to write a web service which takes user name and email and subscribe them to exsiting group. Is there as way i can do this, curl example of doing the same will work.

Comment: That's google Groups the forum.  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!overview there is no api for that.

Comment: Oh so apart from using provide SDK client theres no other way to do this ?

Comment: The provided SDK is NOT for Google Groups it is for Google apps for work it its a different system which also does not give you access to google groups forum.   There is no way to access Google groups the forum programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

There is **no** way to programmatically add users to [Google Groups forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!overview).

The link you have supplied is for the [Google Admin SDK](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/insert) which is for administering Google Admin accounts and has nothing to do with Google Groups the forum.